# Drop down list of products has a different ID each time page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I am using Selenium IDE to do some repetitive form filling tasks for a web app. Part of the process involves selecting a group of products and then choosing some of the base products from that group. For example: I want to see all painting and wallpaper products under the DIY and Hardware section. In Selenium it correctly identifies and selects the DIY and Hardware section. This generates a new set of drop down lists appear then, where I should be able to choose 'paint' and 'wallpaper'. Selenium gives an error here:

```
[error] Element id=selectgroup_RT_PAINT_ca9368dd-ddc0-4ade-a17f-f0e5a56e5e23_1 not found
```

The problem is with the letter and number sequence after `RT_PAINT` This appears to be a unique value each time the drop down lists are generated, even though they always contain the same values. Is there a way around this?

This is the HTML of the Selenium task:

```
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>id=selectgroup_RT_PAINT_ca9368dd-ddc0-4ade-a17f-f0e5a56e5e23_1</td>
    <td>label=Dulux</td>
</tr>
```

I'm new to Selenium so I don't even know what to try, hence no code example. Is there w way to change to `id like...` rather than `id=`

Thanks in advance everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vlad you were almost right but you can't reference Id's like that apparently. When referencing ID it must be exact match. You can use the CSS however to use the prefix rule.

I was able to get around it using the following:

```
css=select[id^="selectgroup_RT_PAINT_"]
```

Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

Try to look for a partial id.

```
id^='selectgroup_RT_PAINT_'
```

See this link for more examples: http://sauceio.com/index.php/2010/01/selenium-totw-css-selectors-in-selenium-demystified/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using selenium IDE, just record and play whatever you want then perform the following:

1. Select the command line that throws error
2. click on target dropdown and select any other locator like relative xpath or other that doesnot include that random sequence.
3. Re-run the test case.